vscode extention - webViewPanel button does nothing
I am new to VSCode extensions and am trying to create a webViewPanel where a user can send a request to an api and the response is pasted in a new text document. The trouble I am having is that the button to send the request does nothing, it doesn't even trigger the panel.webview.onDidReceiveMessage function to run the custom function requestTemplate. I have added and changed a few things after doing some web search, even asked ChatGPT, with no luck.
Below are copies of the extension.js and package.json files.
Many thanks in advance for any help to get the button to work and call the function.
extension.js
const vscode = require('vscode');
const axios = require('axios');


function activate(context) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('newextension.requestTemplateText', () => {
        const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
            'newextensionPanel', 
            'Request Template', 
            vscode.ViewColumn.Two,
            {}
        );

        panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent();

        // Handle messages from the webview
        panel.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(async message => {
            console.log("value of message: " + message)
            // Check if the message contains the parameter text
            switch (message.command) {
                case 'requestTemplate': 
                    text = message.text;
                    await requestTemplate(text);
                    return;
            }
        }, undefined, context.subscriptions);
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

async function requestTemplate(parameter) { //<-- Method I want triggered
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://httpbin.org/get?text=${encodeURIComponent(parameter)}`); //<-- API has not been created yet, using this for testing

        vscode.workspace.openTextDocument({ content: JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2), language: "json" }).then(doc => {
            vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc, vscode.ViewColumn.One);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        vscode.window.showErrorMessage('Error fetching data from the API');
        console.error(error);
    }
}

function getWebviewContent() {
    return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Request Template Text</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Request Template Text</h1>
        <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter your coding question:"><br><br>
        <button onclick="requestTemplate()">Request Template</button> <-- The button in question
        <script> <-- I have tried to add this in the header but still does not work
            const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
            console.log('Sending message to extension:', { command: 'requestTemplate', text: document.getElementById('text').value });
            function requestTemplate() {
                const text = document.getElementById('text').value;
                vscode.postMessage({
                    command: 'requestTemplate',
                    text: parameter
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    `;
}

exports.activate = activate;

package.json
{
  "name": "newextension",
  "displayName": "newExtension",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.88.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": ["onCommand:newextension.requestTemplateText"],
  "main": "./extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "newextension.requestTemplateText",
        "title": "Request Template Text"
      }
    ],
    "webviewPanels": [
      {
        "viewType": "newextensionPanel",
        "title": "Request Template",
        "webviewOptions": {
          "retainContextWhenHidden": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.x",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "vscode": "^1.2.3"
  },
  "extensionDependencies": [],
  "private": true,
  "webview": {
    "retainContextWhenHidden": true
  }
}


why do you use onclick=, connect an event handler to the button, and add a log statement to see if it gets called

Thanks rioV8. I did try using event handler with no luck, however I may have uncovered another issue that may be the root cause. I checked out the Developer tool to inspect the web panel and there is an error: Blocked script execution in {index.html?*} because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set. , even though it looks like I have the correct CSP in the HTML script. I will do a bit more digging and close this question(and open a new one) if resolving the error fixes the issue with the button.

do you have the Typing Cat example running

I haven't but after looking at the page for it, I found that I did not add enableScripts: true to the vscode.window.createWebviewPanel function call.

After reviewing the Typing Cat example mentioned by rioV8,  I found that I did not add enableScripts: true to the vscode.window.createWebviewPanel function call in 'extension.js' file. The function call should look like this:
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
   'newextensionPanel', 
   'Request Template', 
   vscode.ViewColumn.Two,
   {enableScripts: true}
);

Many thanks @rioV8 for your assistance.
